# Request-scoped service undefined in custom validaor

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm encountering trouble leveraging `moduleRef` in conjunction with a `Request`-scoped custom provider in a custom decorator. In particular, using the `moduleRef.resolve()` method, the scoped service is still coming in as undefined. I've been following [these instructions](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref) for using Dependency Injection within the request scope to no avail.

**the request-scoped service**

```
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class RequestService {
  private isCoffee: boolean;

  setIsCoffee(drink: string) {
    this.isCoffee = ['mocha', 'espresso', 'latte'].includes(drink);
  }

  getIsCoffee(): boolean {
    return this.isCoffee;
  }
}
```

**request.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestService } from './request.service';

@Module({
  exports: [RequestService],
  providers: [RequestService],
})
export class RequestModule {}
```

**custom decorator**

```
import {/*...*/}

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'IsCoffeeValidator', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class IsCoffeeValidator
  implements ValidatorConstraintInterface, OnModuleInit
{
  private requestService: RequestService;
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request,
    // @Inject(RequestService) private requestService: RequestService, // A normal DI doesn't work
    private moduleRef: ModuleRef,
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(this.request);
    console.log('In onModuleInit'); // Not logged because this is [dependent upon a request-scoped service][2](?)
    this.requestService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(
      RequestService,
      contextId,
      { strict: false },
    );
  }
  async validate(type: string, { object }: ValidationArguments) {
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(this.request);
    // Fails with "cannot read property resolve of undefined"
    this.requestService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(
      RequestService,
      contextId,
      { strict: false },
    );
    if (this.requestService.getIsCoffee()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
{/*...*}
```

**coffee module**

```
import {/*...*/}

@Module({
  controllers: [CoffeeController],
  imports: [RequestModule],
  providers: [IsCoffeeValidator, RequestService],
})
export class CoffeeModule {}
```

**coffee.dto.ts**

```
import { IsCoffee } from '../../is-coffee.decorator';

export class CoffeeDto {
  @IsCoffee()
  drink: string;
}
```

**Coffee Controller**

```
import {/*...*/}

@Controller('coffee')
export class CoffeeController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(RequestService) private readonly requestService: RequestService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  checkDrink(@Body() body: CoffeeDto) {
    console.log(body);
    return this.requestService.getIsCoffee(); // should always return true, due to passing CoffeeDto validation
  }
}
```

---

[Here's a contrived repo](https://github.com/schroeder-g/nest-module-ref-bug) that replicates the issue. hitting POST http://localhost:3000/coffee throws the error `Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined`.

How do I properly pull a request-scoped service into a custom validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you inject `@Inject(REQUEST)` you still make your validator constraint as REQUEST scoped [which is not possible](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5677).

> How do I properly pull a request-scoped service into a custom validator?

Short answer: you don't. I'd create a custom pipe for something like that, so that it *can* be request scoped, rather than forcing class-valdiator to fit your needs. class-validator is great for simple constraints and schema validations, but if you need full business logic it's usually better to go with a custom pipe

Comment: Hey Jay, pipes indeed seem like the natural solution for this use case. Thank you for the response, recommendation, and for surfacing of the prior threads. 

On that note, given the amount of discussion around this, it seems like a worthwhile caution to include in the docs. 

Nonetheless I will be sure to be more thorough in searching the GH Issues in the future.